# How does a nuclear reactor start?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

okay first I want to say I know there is a lot of video on YouTube that show a reactor starting but I was wounding like how it starts if anyone has like a diagram or something of the process of a reactor starting that would be amazing I am really curious about this thanks. If anyone is confused want to clarify a cold reactor start. Also i am quite young to be getting into this only in year 9 so if anyone answers try to make it make some sense since I normal want to know how every part of it works it confusing ik

Answer (score 2):

Every single reactor built in the world possesses an explicit, step-by-step startup procedure that is used to *bring the reactor on-line* from a cold start.

The startup procedure varies from one reactor design to another but the basic process involves slowly increasing the reactivity of the reactor by withdrawing control rods from the core. Those control rods are made of material that absorbs fission neutrons and if they are fully inserted into the reactor core, they remove enough neutrons to stop the chain reaction. Pulling the rods out increases the number of neutrons available to produce fissions in the fuel, which then starts to get hot.

It also involves starting up the cooling water pumps and the pressurized lubrication system for the turbine rotor and the alternator bearings, and in some cases pre-rotating them to ensure full oil flow in all the bearings.

The whole startup process requires many hours to perform because the entire system must be protected against sudden changes in temperature.

If there are any reactor operators out there I invite them to weigh in on this, but the section of the reactor operator's manual dealing with a cold start will probably be at least a hundred pages long or more.

Comment: For this like what is used to increase the nutrons like how in a fission bomb they slam two urianium cores or what every and that is what cascades and causes the kaboom so that the cores make it that why I want to know what happens in a reactor to start it might just be confusing myself

Comment: i will edit my answer. -NN